# php foreach with sql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have an array called "questions" that I am trying to INSERT into mysql with foreach. Array looks like this:

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
        [booking_id] => 936
        [question_id] => a
        [value] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [booking_id] => 936
        [question_id] => b
        [value] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        [booking_id] => 936
        [question_id] => c
        [value] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        [booking_id] => 936
        [question_id] => d
        [value] => 1
        )
     )
```

FOREACH looks like this:

```
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $_POST['questions'] as $row ) {

    $sql[] = '("'.$row['booking_id'].'", "'.$row['question_id'].'", '.$row['value'].')';
}

mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (booking_id, question_id, value) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

The foreach simply inserts the first item in the array into the table and doesn't loop through the entire array.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST contains what you think it does?

Comment: print_r($_POST['questions']); gives the above array

Comment: all booking_id is 936  ..?

Comment: If `booking_id` is your primary key and cannot have duplicates and every record has `id=936` then that's your problem. Try adding ` or die(mysql_error())` to the end of your `mysql_query()` statement.

Comment: spotted the problem - it's the primary key. obviously not meant to be. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually duplicated the code and got it run on an actual MySQL server perfectly, no mistakes in the code as far as I can see.

The only problem I can guess is a unique index that prevents from adding multiple records under the same booking_id.

Is there a primary / unique index on the booking_id field that prevents from adding multiple records?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This seems like something worth looking into.

Comment: @maackle If someone has something to ask about the question, it should be a comment. If they are trying to answer the question, it should be worded as an answer.

Comment: @msg7086 - thanks. that is indeed the problem. many thanks. silly thing to miss.

Comment: @winterblood Thanks for the tip. I'm new to the community and not that good in constructing my words. It's really hard for me to ask for a clarification in the comment without answering the question itself.

Comment: @msg7086 Don't worry, we were all new once, and the StackOverflow way of doing things can be **very** particular sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

It's already time to use PDO or MySQLi with PHP.
This is a working example. You could replace `$arr` with `$_POST` and refactor a bit to suit your needs.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dachi');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$arr = array(
  array(
    'booking_id' => 936,
    'question_id' => 15,
    'value' => 4,
  ),
  array(
    'booking_id' => 936,
    'question_id' => 15,
    'value' => 3,
  ),
);

foreach ($arr as $rec) {
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`booking_id`,`question_id`,`value`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
  // You will probably need to change 'iii'
  // i = integer
  // s = string
  // So you might have something like isi if you need like that or sss
  $stmt->bind_param('iii', $rec['booking_id'], $rec['question_id'], $rec['value']);
  $d = $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: does mysqli/PDO require an install on the server? just got back into all this for a new project and it seems like a bit has changed!

Comment: You have to install PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setup.php but the mysqli extension was introduced with PHP version 5.0.0.

Comment: Btw, your code is not secure. rumor that is "truish": _Nowadays 'everyone' is using prepared statements for security_

Comment: I know. I was going to run mysql_real_escape_string on the variables. Looks like this method is a bit outdated though.

Comment: mysql is deprecated as stated on php website. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php You can see it in red.

Answer (score -2):

```
// $sql query value to get data in DB
$branches= array();
$sql = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  array_push($question, $row);

}
 // this part to loop data fetch in sql
   $branch_type = '';
   foreach ($question as $NBU) {

    $sql[] = '("'.$row['booking_id'].'", "'.$row['question_id'].'", '.$row['value'].')';

    }

   mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (booking_id, question_id, value) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

dont use $_POST['questions']  because foreach only read array data.

Comment: try to see if the variable is in array. the one you loop